# Write logic gate equation from circuit

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, math

[image]

Above is the circuit with my attempt and how I viewed it. I'm wondering if there's anyone that can confirm if I got it right? The middle red line that goes through the Not gate confuses me.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: This is not an answer, but the way to verify this is for each stimulus ABC, you go through the circuit and write the logical states for each node. You will eventually validate your answer this way.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is correct.

A good way to know when line merge is to add a dot at the crossing.

I advice you to use a Karnaugh map to verify your solution (for next time). This provide a easy way to check and a good way too shorter the equation (when it is possible)

Answer (score 0):

Yes your answer looks good.

You are right, lines crossing without dots is hard to read sometimes, but when they cross completely like that assume they are not connected. Nobody, in their right mind, would draw two 90 degree bends knee to knee.